# Syncing WP Database Changes Between Environments: How To Handle Merging w/o touching database

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, migration, import, export, plugin-wpml

I have a staging site which is originally a clone of the live site.
On a staging site, I made some changes such as creating new pages, installing new plugins, adding new medias etc.

Meanwhile the live version has been changed by a client as well. New pages are added, new plugins are added, new users, new orders, new subscribers...

Now I want to know the best practice of how to push the staging site to live site in a case like this.

It's a multilingual woocommerce website. so as the WPML plugin team suggested, I've purchased import/export plugins(https://www.wpallimport.com/) so that I can import the newly added data on live site into the staging site.

Unfortunately I found I cannot import data with a few clicks. I gotta map every single field (bunch of fields) one bye one extra carefully, plus I gotta do the same thing for all languages.

We have gravity forms and I just found out I need another paid plugin to import all the entries in gravity form.

Now it makes me wonder if my approach is really right.

I mean, is this supposed to be so complicated and cost this much?

What I'm trying to do is make everything except for the changes I made identical with the live site. And after that, I wanna migrate the staging site to live site.

But there's no way for me to know every single change they've mede on a live site and I don't think they remember either.

They may have changed some small settings on one plugin, I never know.

In this case, I wonder if I should rather import the pages I made and plugins I added on a staging site into the live site while shutting down the live site.

I've read thru many articles about it, and I'm trying to follow the way wpml plugin team suggested, but still I wonder if this is really a right way in my case.

I prefer not to touch the database cuz I'm not very used to it and can mess things up.

If there's anyone who experienced this, could you please give me some advice?

How would you handle in a case like this?

Thank you,

Comment: I don't keep content in sync with live sites, just the theme code. When I make changes to the theme or any custom plugins I upload the changes to a dev site so the client can see. If it's ok I move that to the live site and they can then start to use the new features in new content. They can use the dev site to test things out but when the changes are moved then they either create the content again on the live site or if it's a new post type or similar then we use allimport to import that content (It has an option to export a bundle that doesn't require you to map the fields).

Comment: Thank you Robert. So your approach is something like you made some changes, say, created new pages and installed some new plugins, and you import only these new pages and new plugins in live site, correct?

Comment: I only move code to a live site, never content if it can be avoided. It's very rare that my clients would want me to produce a load of content on a dev site and move it. They just want to see that it works like it should and then away they go on the live site. I think the only time I've used allimport for this is when a company recently wanted an events section and they added all the content to the dev site. It wasn't great as I use acf and the image id's don't match once anything has been changed so I had to manually update those anyway.

Comment: Robert thank you for your reply. So basically you do not migrate the entire dev site to the live site, right? When you change something on a dev, and if client approved it, you just manually move (or import) only that code. Am I understanding right?  If the change you made is relatively big, do you shut down the live site while you are working on it?